# scikit-learn error although it is properly installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

My code is as follows:

```
from imblearn import over_sampling
```

I get this error:

```
cannot import name 'DistanceMetric' from 'sklearn.metrics'
```

A simple import on imblearn is giving the same error. I tried reinstalling scikit learn and scipy, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is working fine on my computer, it must be your installation. Try uninstalling scikit-learn before reinstalling.

Edit:
If that is not working I would try running:
python -m pip show scikit-learn

uninstall sklearn, delete the directory for sklearn, reboot the computer, and reinstall sklearn.

Comment: It works fine on my one computer too, but not on other one. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-learn but same error

Comment: Do you get the same error when you import it direct? from sklearn.metrics import DistanceMetric

Comment: Yes, I get the same error